# Is there any PHP function to convert number to currency with thousands separators?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

Is there any PHP function to convert an `integer` to Lakh and Crore?

```
900800 -> 9,00,800
500800 -> 5,00,800
```

Comment: `number_format():` http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: @Rizier123 OP is requesting Indian number formatting, which `number_format` does not do.

Comment: @ColinvH How should i know that that is `Indian number format`? (But good thing to know)

Comment: @Rizier123 After 1,000 they group by 100s (e.g., 9,00,800 and 3,21,00,500).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have added `Yii` in your question tags, you can do this in `Yii`'s way like below:

```
Yii::app()->language='en_IN';
// Output: Lakh 9,00,800
echo Yii::app()->numberFormatter->formatCurrency('900800', 'Lakh');

// Output: ₹ 5,00,800
echo Yii::app()->numberFormatter->formatCurrency('500800', 'INR');
```

Comment: its output 5,00,800.00, How to temove .00 from this string

Answer (score 1):

For most locales, use `number_format`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

For India (Lakh & Crore) use `formatInIndianStyle` provided in this comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#40558